# RequestDispatcher forward() does not return all page body to client

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dispatcher

I have Filter that forward Url to Url.jsp (because of removing .jsp from url)

ّCommonFilter.java

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String path = "";
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    if (!isPage(uri)) {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        return;
    }
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();

    if (uri.length() > contextPath.length() && isPage(uri)) {
        if (uri.equals("/")) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        } else {
            path = uri.substring(contextPath.length() + 1, uri.length());
        }


        try {
            req.getRequestDispatcher(path + ".jsp").include(req, res);
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(path + ".jsp");
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

but when i enter example.com/index in browser,
the page does not contain all body and some htmls at the end of index.jsp file not sending to client
but if i remove the filter, it loads index.jsp completely

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code?

Comment: it doesn't reach end of the code

Comment: meaning? which line?

Comment: for example last 30 line of index.jsp doest not run when using dispatcher

Comment: I meant place a breakpoint inside doFilter and step through the method.

Comment: i put breakpoint,it parses all lines of index.jsp file, but it doesn't send them to browser

Comment: Did you step into chain.filter?